# I am encountering an error while developing website in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was starting to develop website using Next.js 13. I am getting an error message when I try to access localhost:3000:
-Error1:
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching "<div>" in .
-Error2:
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
This is my layout.tsx:

```
import {cn} from '@/lib/utils'

import '@/styles/globals.css'
import {Inter} from "next/font/google"
import Navbar from '@/components/ui/Navbar'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Breadit',
  description: 'A Reddit clone built with Next.js and TypeScript.',
}

const inter = Inter({subsets: ['latin']})

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en' className={cn('bg-white text-slate-900 antialiased light', 
    inter.className
    )}>
      <body className='min-h-screen pt-12 bg-slate-50 antialiased'>
        <Navbar />

        <div className='container max-w-7xl mx-auto h-full pt-12'>
          {children}
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

This is my Navbar.tsx. I am concerned maybe here I have any mistake:

```
import { Link } from "lucide-react";
import { Icons } from "./Icons";
import { buttonVariants } from "./Button";
 
const Navbar =  () => {
    return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 inset-x-0 h-fit bg-zinc-100 border -b border-zinc-300 z-[10] py-2">
        <div className="container max-w-7xl h-full mx-auto flex items-center justify-between gap-2">
            {/* Logo */}
            <Link href="/" className="flex items-center gap-2">
                <Icons.logo className="h-8 w-8 sm:h-6 sm:w-6" />
                <div className="hidden text-zinc-700 text-sm font-medium md:block">Breadit</div>
            </Link>
            suppressHydrationWarning={true}
            {/* Search */}

            <Link href="/sign-in" className={buttonVariants()}>Sign In</Link>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

This is my Icons.tsx:

```
import { LucideProps } from "lucide-react";

export const Icons = {
    logo: (props:LucideProps) => (
        <svg {...props} viewBox='0 0 497 497'>
      <g>
        <path
          d='m392 30c-71.75 0-71.75-30-143.5-30l128.5 497h30c33.137 0 60-26.863 60-60v-228.526c18.555-18.938 30-44.867 30-73.474 0-57.99-47.01-105-105-105z'
          fill='#c87044'
        />
        <path
          d='m437 437-45-377c-41.895 0-63.904-18.405-83.322-34.644-16.942-14.167-30.323-25.356-60.178-25.356-71.75 0-71.75 30-143.5 30-57.99 0-105 47.01-105 105 0 28.607 11.445 54.537 30 73.474v228.526c0 33.137 26.863 60 60 60h287c33.137 0 60-26.863 60-60z'
          fill='#db905a'
        />
        <path
          d='m392 60-15 407h30c16.542 0 30-13.458 30-30v-228.526c0-7.851 3.077-15.388 8.571-20.996 13.819-14.103 21.429-32.74 21.429-52.478 0-41.355-33.645-75-75-75z'
          fill='#ffd185'
        />
        <path
          d='m407 437v-228.526c0-15.796 6.088-30.708 17.143-41.991 8.291-8.462 12.857-19.643 12.857-31.483 0-41.355-20.187-75-45-75-41.895 0-63.904-9.203-83.322-17.322-16.942-7.083-30.323-12.678-60.178-12.678-29.856 0-43.236 5.595-60.177 12.678-19.419 8.119-41.429 17.322-83.323 17.322-41.355 0-75 33.645-75 75 0 19.738 7.61 38.375 21.429 52.479 5.494 5.607 8.571 13.145 8.571 20.995v228.526c0 16.542 13.458 30 30 30h287c16.542 0 30-13.458 30-30z'
          fill='#ffe8c2'
        />
        <g fill='#ffd185'>
          <circle cx='392' cy='135' r='7.5' />
          <circle cx='362' cy='165' r='7.5' />
          <circle cx='105' cy='377' r='7.5' />
          <circle cx='135' cy='407' r='7.5' />
          <circle cx='105' cy='135' r='7.5' />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
    )
}
```